# Заменить числа списка в цикле for

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Есть небольшой тестовый код, который делает проверку значений в списке. Если значение не удовлетворяет условие, то оно будет заменено на эталонное значение. Чтобы записать новые значение мне приходится создавать новый пустой список в начале и записывать всё в него. Можно как-нибудь перезаписывать число в исходном списке без создания new_step_time_row? И какие могут быть рекомендации, чтобы сделать код лаконичнее?

```
dec_rate = 0
# Количество считанных значений в секунду
values_per_second = 4250 / (dec_rate + 1)
# Эталонное время между каждым новым значением
reference_time = 1 / values_per_second
# Доверительный интервал
сonfidence_interval_up = reference_time * 1.5
сonfidence_interval_down = reference_time * 0.5

step_time_row = [0.00023529, 0.00036, 0.00038, 0.00023458456,
                 0.00021529, 0.00019529, 0.00010529, 0.00009529,
                 0.00028529, 0.00036529, 0.00029529, 0.00021529]

new_step_time_row = []

# Цикл, который проверяет входит ли время в допустимые пределы.
# Если не входит, то заменяется эталонным временем.
for number in step_time_row:
    if number > сonfidence_interval_up or number < сonfidence_interval_down:
        number = reference_time
    new_step_time_row.append(number)

print(new_step_time_row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если главное требование именно лаконичность кода, а за одно и скорость при больших наборах данных, то я бы сделал вообще в  одну строку, через numpy (и никаких циклов):

```
step_time_row=np.array(step_time_row)
step_time_row[(step_time_row > сonfidence_interval_up) | (step_time_row< сonfidence_interval_down)] = reference_time
```

Comment: Объёмы данных получаемых от датчика действительно очень большие. Я правильно понимаю, что в этом случае стоит совсем отказаться от стандартных пайтоновских списках и использовать только массивы nampy, чтобы повысить производительность программы?

Comment: Если объемы "действительно очень большие" то надо не "совсем отказаться от стандартных пайтоновских списках" а ДАВНО отказаться от пайтоновских списков. Изначально, при выборе основных проектных решений.

Comment: Спасибо, в будущем учту этот момент!

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение замены элементов непосредственно в исходном списке:

```
# Значение number меняется в диапазоне от 0 до
# индекса последнего элемента списка, который
# равен длине списка за минусом 1.
for number in range(len(step_time_row)):
    # Если элемент с индексом number больше или меньше сonfidence_interval,
    if step_time_row[number] > сonfidence_interval_up or step_time_row[number] < сonfidence_interval_down:
        step_time_row[number] = reference_time # то он заменяется на эталон
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Чуть более лаконично через функцию map. Так же там можно было использовать lambda функцию.

```
dec_rate = 0
# Количество считанных значений в секунду
values_per_second = 4250 / (dec_rate + 1)
# Эталонное время между каждым новым значением
reference_time = 1 / values_per_second
# Доверительный интервал
сonfidence_interval_up = reference_time * 1.5
сonfidence_interval_down = reference_time * 0.5

step_time_row = [0.00023529, 0.00036, 0.00038, 0.00023458456,
                 0.00021529, 0.00019529, 0.00010529, 0.00009529,
                 0.00028529, 0.00036529, 0.00029529, 0.00021529]

new_step_time_row = []

# Цикл, который проверяет входит ли время в допустимые пределы.
# Если не входит, то заменяется эталонным временем.
for number in step_time_row:
    if number > сonfidence_interval_up or number < сonfidence_interval_down:
        number = reference_time
    new_step_time_row.append(number)

print(new_step_time_row)


def change_number(number):
    if number > сonfidence_interval_up or number < сonfidence_interval_down:
        number = reference_time
    return number


new_step_time_row_v2 = list(map(change_number, step_time_row))
print(new_step_time_row == new_step_time_row_v2)
print(new_step_time_row_v2)
```